# Desktop RSS reader that supports Single Sign On?

Tags: rss, single-sign-on

I'm looking for Windows desktop RSS reader application that supports single sign on. Could you recommend one please?

EDIT: There are some websites, which need authentication. I have an account and I can login to the website in order to see the contents. If you open the link for the feed in the browser, it prompts you with a popup to enter your username and password. This popup can be avoided, because it supports SSO and the feeds are readable later from whithin the browser's (Firefox) feed reader.

The thing is, I do not want to use the browser for that. I want an RSS reader, which can do this automatically and notify me when there is some new articles in the feed.

Comment: It depends on what do you mean by "single sign on".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It hasn't been updated in a while, but SharpReader lets me see password-protected feeds and remembers my login info.  http://www.sharpreader.net/
(Sorry if I'm misunderstanding SSO)

Comment: I found also one more - RSS Bandit.

Comment: Unfortunately, this is abandonware.  I'm not sure whatever happened to Luke Hutteman, but I hope he's okay (srsly, not joking here).